# converting ByteArray File from server to a Image in imageView

Tags: android, arrays, image, filestream

I have a ByteArray File on my server which I want to read and display in a ImageView.

How can I do that?

Comment: convert your byteArray to a bitmap then set the `ImageView`'s bitmap. `Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(myByteArray, 0, byteArray.length);`

Comment: Instead of adding "Solved" to the subject line, please accept your/the answer to indicate your question/problem was solved.

Comment: I have to wait some hours before I can accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

convert your byteArray to a bitmap then set the `ImageView`'s bitmap.

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(myByteArray, 0, byteArray.length);//myByteArray is the byte array you want to convert.
ImageView myImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.custom_image);//get a reference to your ImageView
myImage.setImageBitmap(bm)//set the ImageView bitmap
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I download/read the ByteArray from the server ?

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution, here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // show The Image
    new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
    .execute("http://myURL");

}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```